# Test RPC service developed in using TWIRP

Tags: go, protocol-buffers, rpc, twirp

I'd like to test a sample Twirp RPC service. The sample service is from [Twirp official website](https://twitchtv.github.io/twirp/docs/intro.html).

Protobuf definition is as follows:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package helloservice;
option go_package = "helloservice";

service HelloWorld {
  rpc Hello(HelloReq) returns (HelloResp);
}

message HelloReq {
  string subject = 1;
}

message HelloResp {
  string text = 1;
}
```

Server implementation:

```
type HelloWorldServer struct{}

func (s *HelloWorldServer) Hello(ctx context.Context, req *pb.HelloReq) (*pb.HelloResp, error) {
    return &pb.HelloResp{Text: "Hello " + req.Subject}, nil
}
```

I tried the [solution suggested here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52080545/14041681), but there's some confusion in ClientConn vs HTTPClient. So far, I have this

```
var Once sync.Once
const bufSize = 1024 * 1024
var listener *bufconn.Listener

func InitTestServer(t *testing.T) *gomock.Controller {
    Once.Do(func(){
        listener = bufconn.Listen(bufSize)
        server := &server.HelloWorldServer{}
        twirpHandler := pb.NewHelloWorldServer(server, nil)
        mux := http.NewServeMux()
        mux.Handle(twirpHandler.PathPrefix(), twirpHandler)
        httpServer := http.Server{
            Handler: mux,
        }
        go func() {
            if err := httpServer.Serve(listener); err != nil {
                if err != http.ErrServerClosed {
                    log.Fatalln("Failed to start http listener", "error", err)
                }
            }
        }()
    })
    ctrl := gomock.NewController(t)
    return ctrl
}

func bufDialer(context.Context, string) (net.Conn, error) {
    return listener.Dial()
}

func TestCreate(t *testing.T) {
    //ctrl := InitTestServer(t)
    InitTestServer(t)
    ctx := context.Background()
    conn, err := grpc.DialContext(ctx, "", grpc.WithInsecure(), grpc.WithContextDialer(bufDialer))
    // conn is of type *ClientConn
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("Failed to dial bufnet: %v", err)
    }
    defer conn.Close()
    //NewHelloWorldJSONClient accepts only HTTPClient
    client := pb.NewHelloWorldJSONClient(conn)
    response, err := client.Hello(ctx, &pb.HelloReq{
        Subject: "sample",
    })
    t.Log(response, err)
}
```

Any way to convert one into the other, or any other way to test out a Twirp RPC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `net/http/httptest` to accomplish a test of this kind.

1. Create the handler using `pb.NewHelloWorldServer` and giving it the server implementation struct.
2. Create `httptest.NewServer` using the handler.
3. Use the httptest server's `.URL` in `pb.NewHelloWorldJSONClient` (or protobuf, or both).

As a quick example:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptest"
    "testing"

    pb "github.com/3ventic/twirphelloworld/rpc"
)

// InitTestServer initializes a test server for HelloWorld and returns its address
func InitTestServer() string {
    handler := pb.NewHelloWorldServer(&HelloWorldServer{})
    server := httptest.NewServer(handler)
    return server.URL
}

func TestHello(t *testing.T) {
    url := InitTestServer()
    clients := map[string]pb.HelloWorld{
        "json": pb.NewHelloWorldJSONClient(url, http.DefaultClient),
        "pb":   pb.NewHelloWorldProtobufClient(url, http.DefaultClient),
    }

    for typ, client := range clients {
        t.Run(typ, func(t *testing.T) {
            ctx := context.Background()
            result, err := client.Hello(ctx, &pb.HelloReq{
                Subject: "test",
            })
            if err != nil {
                t.Error(err)
                t.FailNow()
            }
            if result.Text != "Hello test" {
                t.Errorf("result didn't match 'Hello test', was '%s'", result.Text)
            }
        })
    }
}
```

[Full example available here](https://github.com/3ventic/HelloWorldTwirp)