# grpc testing code exit 1 with 'rpc error: code = Unimplemented desc = method Hello not implemented'

Tags: go, testing, grpc, grpc-go

**Environment**

```
go version go1.17.4 linux/amd64

libprotoc 3.6.1
```

**Problem**

I'm testing grpc server and client implemented by Go.
First, I made proto definition and generate pb codes by protoc command.
I referred this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42102496/testing-a-grpc-service).
Following the error is printed by minimum codes to reproduce my error.

**Error**

```
$ go test
--- FAIL: TestHello (0.00s)
    main_test.go:49: failed to Hello: rpc error: code = Unimplemented desc = method Hello not implemented
FAIL
exit status 1
FAIL    github.com/Asuha-a/test/test    0.003s
```

**Code**

hello.proto

```proto
syntax = "proto3";

option go_package = "github.com/Asuha-a/test/pb";

package hello;

service Hello {
  rpc Hello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply) {}
}

message HelloRequest {
  string foo = 1;
}

message HelloReply {
  string bar = 1;
}
```

main_test.go

```golang
package hello_test

import (
    "context"
    "log"
    "net"
    "testing"

    "github.com/Asuha-a/test/pb"
    "google.golang.org/grpc"
    "google.golang.org/grpc/test/bufconn"
)

type server struct {
    pb.UnimplementedHelloServer
}

const bufSize = 1024 * 1024

var lis *bufconn.Listener

func init() {
    lis = bufconn.Listen(bufSize)
    s := grpc.NewServer()
    pb.RegisterHelloServer(s, &server{})
    go func() {
        if err := s.Serve(lis); err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("server exited with error: %v", err)
        }
    }()
}

func bufDialer(context.Context, string) (net.Conn, error) {
    return lis.Dial()
}

func TestHello(t *testing.T) {
    ctx := context.Background()
    conn, err := grpc.DialContext(ctx, "bufnet", grpc.WithContextDialer(bufDialer), grpc.WithInsecure())
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("failed to dial bufnet: %v", err)
    }
    defer conn.Close()
    client := pb.NewHelloClient(conn)
    r, err := client.Hello(ctx, &pb.HelloRequest{
        Foo: "foo",
    })
    if err != nil {
        t.Fatalf("failed to Hello: %v", err) //49th line prints the error
    }
    log.Println(r)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your test you are calling `pb.RegisterHelloServer(s, &server{})` using the  `server` struct. However this struct only embeds `pb.UnimplementedHelloServer` and declares no methods. Hence, you can only get `codes.Unimplemented` back when calling any of its RPCs.

You have to implement the `Hello` rpc on the `server` struct:

```
func (s *server) Hello(ctx context.Context, req *pb.HelloRequest) (*pb.HelloReply, error) {
    return &pb.HelloReply{}, nil
}
```

**Note:** embedding `pb.UnimplementedHelloServer` makes the gRPC server implementations forward compatible at the expense of compile-time checks. To forgo forward compatibility and catch these errors at compile time, you can embed instead `pb.UnsafeHelloServer`.